# ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199) Unhandled Exception: could not lanch Call in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

this coud for mack icon call with INKWILL

```
 _Call() async {
const _url = 'tel:01140654053' ;
if (await canLaunch(_url)) {
  await launch(_url);
} else {
  throw 'could not lanch ';
}
```

}

and this error

```
E/flutter ( 8522): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: could not lanch 
E/flutter ( 8522): #0      _MyHomePageState._Call (package:oonco_helpp/main.dart:105:7)
E/flutter ( 8522): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8522):
```

Answer (score 0):

Android 11 introduced a [tighter security](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility) when interacting with other apps, the [package visibility](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility) concept. This is the cause why `canLaunch` always returns false on Android 11 (API 30) and `launchUrl` will fail when using the [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package.

From [this blog](https://medium.com/flutter-community/package-visibility-for-url-launcher-on-android-11-api-30-7c03cbce76a5), they have introduce a solution for this:

> This can be fixed by configuring your application to make other
> applications that have the `android.intent.action.VIEW` intent filter
> using `<queries>` element in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.
>
> For the `<queries>` element to work, it is recommended you upgrade
> your Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) to version 4.1. In your project level
> gradle file, `android/build.gradle`, do as shown below:
>
> ```
> buildscript {
>
>     repositories {
>         google()
>         jcenter()
>     }
>
>     dependencies {
>         // Using gradle plugin version 4.1.1
>         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> There are other dot versions for earlier versions of the Android
> Gradle Plugins. Find out more from
> [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/07/preparing-your-build-for-package-visibility-in-android-11.html).
>
> After upgrading the gradle plugin and building the app, add this
> element block to your `AndroidManifest.xml` :
>
> ```
> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     package="com.example.sample">
>
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
>
>     <!-- Add the block below to your manifest file to configure apps with action.VIEW intent filters as visible to your app -->
>     <!-- START HERE -->
>     <queries>
>         <intent>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
>             <data android:scheme="https" />
>         </intent>
>     </queries>
>     <!-- END HERE -->
>
>     <application>
>         ...
>     </application>
> </manifest>
> ```
>
> After doing this, rebuild the app and `canLaunch` should return `true`
> and `launchUrl` should also open the url on Android 11 (API 30).